# Wants to exclude special characters. I meant only needed characters in python

Tags: python-3.x

So far tried this. Not succeded.

re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '',str(list_of_vals))

```
['-|3', 'g|11', '4|5', 'E|17', 'l|14', 'W|2', 'D|6', 'o|33', 'b|10', '3|3', 'c|20', ':|11', 'u|13', 'X|1', 'x|34', 'A|9', 'H|4', 'O|11', '5|2', 'p|9', 'j|1', 'h|19', 'y|16', 'm|21', 'R|7', '*|1', '9|2', ')|62', 'T|14', ',|13', 'I|12', 'P|5', '#|1', 'S|8', 'M|2', 'B|2', 'G|3', 'V|4', '@|2', '^|1', '!|18', '%|1', '8|5', '||32', 'w|1', 'd|23', '$|1', 'f|14', 'L|7', 'e|74', 'Y|1', '0|8', '2|4', 't|44', 'C|6', '=|1', 'a|41', '6|3', '.|8', 'z|6', 'i|49', 'n|39', '(|2', '1|6', 'N|12', 'r|30', '/|1', 's|33', 'v|3', 'F|7', '7|4']
```

Comment: What are you considering as special characters?

Comment: Moreover needed only characters

Comment: What are you considering as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=['-|3', 'g|11', '4|5', 'E|17', 'l|14', 'W|2', 'D|6', 'o|33', 'b|10', '3|3', 'c|20', ':|11', 'u|13', 'X|1', 'x|34', 'A|9', 'H|4', 'O|11', '5|2', 'p|9', 'j|1', 'h|19', 'y|16', 'm|21', 'R|7', '*|1', '9|2', ')|62', 'T|14', ',|13', 'I|12', 'P|5', '#|1', 'S|8', 'M|2', 'B|2', 'G|3', 'V|4', '@|2', '^|1', '!|18', '%|1', '8|5', '||32', 'w|1', 'd|23', '$|1', 'f|14', 'L|7', 'e|74', 'Y|1', '0|8', '2|4', 't|44', 'C|6', '=|1', 'a|41', '6|3', '.|8', 'z|6', 'i|49', 'n|39', '(|2', '1|6', 'N|12', 'r|30', '/|1', 's|33', 'v|3', 'F|7', '7|4']
b=[''.join([r for r in e if r in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890"]) for e in a]
```

Try this

Comment: I want's character count's alone. Is that work

Comment: sure let me try it

Comment: @praveena Your question is very unclear, so maybe you should just describe more clearly what *you want* there first.